# Sort the Array with Absolute value only and show real value In C++

Tags: c++

Print the absolute sorted array. See the sample output for clarification.

```
input:  arr = [2, -7, -2, -2, 0]
output: [0, -2, -2, 2, -7]
```

Now I am using a lambda function as a comparator for STL `std::sort` but it's not giving correct answer; a help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
vector<int> absSort(const vector<int>& at)
{
  vector <int> arr = at;
  
  sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [&](const int a, const int b){
    if (abs(a) < abs(b)) return -1;
    if (abs(a) > abs(b)) return 1;
    
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
    
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: And Also may I Know how Lamda function Works with sort STL

Comment: Read the documentation for the comparison-predicate version of std::sort you're using: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort -- notice that the function _"returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second"_.  Your function does not return a boolean, so in fact it will always return true (non-zero) unless the two values are equal.

Comment: C++ is not C (I am assuming you got the 1, 0, -1 from looking at C code).  You're supposed to return either `true` or `false`, not 1, 0, -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparison function is incorrect.  It must return a boolean indicating whether `a` and `b` are in the correct order.

It should be something like this:

```
auto compare = [](int a, int b)
{
    int abs_a = abs(a), abs_b = abs(b);
    if (abs_a < abs_b) return true;
    if (abs_b < abs_a) return false;
    return a < b;
};
```

**Note:** It's generally not a good idea to use automatic capture-by-reference (`[&]`) as it's too easy to accidentally introduce side-effects in your lambdas.  I removed this in my example, as there's actually no need to capture anything anyway.  We could debate style, but as a matter of personal preference, I always make all my captures explicit, whether they are by reference or by value.

Comment: Maybe simply `{ return abs(a) < abs(b); }`?

Comment: No, that would be a deviation from the original example.  It performs a secondary sort for when the absolute values are equal.

Comment: @paddy what about `{ return (abs(a) < abs(b)) || (a < b); }`?

Comment: No.  Consider `a=-4` and `b=2`.  Your suggestion would result in `-4` coming earlier in the sort order than `2` which is incorrect.  Lots of people seem to make this kind of logical error, especially for things like version tests.  On multiple occasions, I've had to contact third-party vendors whose code failed to function after the major version was bumped, for exactly this kind of mistake.

Comment: @paddy when do we capture by reference like use ([&]) can u show difference with some sample code ??

Comment: For example: `int foo = 42; auto bar = [&]() { ++foo; }; bar();` -- when you use `[&]` it will automatically capture `foo` by reference, meaning after you call `bar()` the value of `foo` will be 43.  If you used `[=]` instead, it would automatically capture `foo` by value and so it would not be changed outside the lambda.  If you use `[]` it would result in a compiler error.  My personal preference is to make it explicit: `[&foo]`.  This means you fully intend that value to be captured by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If its abs then does it matter is -2 is before 2 in the sort.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 6> s = { 2, -7, -2, -2, 0, 7 };

    // sort using a custom lambda
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int a, int b)
    {
        if (abs(a) == abs(b))
            return a < b;
        return abs(a) < abs(b);
    });

    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please mind the order the negative ones comes first like if input is say  [2, -7, -2, -2, 0,7]
Then o/p must be [0, -2, -2, 2, -7 , 7]

Comment: Sorry, but you've just invented lambdas here

Comment: @YuriKovalenko read the API for std::sort. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort . I didn't invent anything. Kind of rude.

I also modified it to use a lambda.

Comment: @PaulBaxter sorry if it seemed rude. I know the API for `std::sort`, and your code was completely correct, but my comment was about the fact that you created a struct with an overloaded call operator, but that is exactly what lambdas do, but with less boilerplate code, and I didn't see any reasons to use an explicit struct instead of a lambda here

Answer (score 0):

If you want something easy to do, just Add cossine/2, the result become a little down for negatives, little up for positives and does not inflict the integer part, not good for production thou.

```
  sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](auto a, auto b){
      return abs(a + cos(a)/2.) < abs(b + cos(b)/2.);
  });
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7G9n38